# Erro:SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Tags: discord.js

i cant idendify the problem, please help.

usuário = user

acao = action/act

"Erro:SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration"

const members = message.guild.members.cache.filter( m => m._roles.includes('762063845984174130'));

```
const mamado = usuário || member.get(Array.from(adms.keys())[Math.floor(Math.random() * member.size)]);

const ações = ['mamou graciosamente', 'mamou delicadamente', 'MORDEU', 'mamou como um profissional'];

const gifs = {
  'mamou graciosamente': ['https://media1.tenor.com/images/7ef6a2fcaba846d7fc1ad99a9b952d5e/tenor.gif?itemid=4934925',
  ],


  'mamou delicadamente': ['https://media1.tenor.com/images/37cf12caba4ebedfb6bafa4bcce5bab7/tenor.gif?itemid=10816189',
  ],


  'MORDEU': ['https://pa1.narvii.com/5757/df946fe46d73864e6dd53143727549e1d0135a6e_00.gif'],


  'mamou como um profissional': ['media1.tenor.com/images/76f9de536c5e20d278a507df28dfba4a/tenor.gif',
  'https://media1.tenor.com/images/8decdf7fedc618aaa22b2f4cd8fba5d2/tenor.gif?itemid=14835705'],


};

const acao = ações[Math.floor(Math.random() * ações.length)];
const gif = gifs[acao][Math.floor(Math.random() * gifs[acao].length)];

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${message.author} ${acao} ${mamado}.`)
    .setImage(gif)
    .setFooter('ehehehehehehe'), message.client.user.avatarURL();

message.send({ embed: embed }).then(() => {
  message.delete()
});
```

Comment: Post your full code. Check if you have declared a variable with `const` without initializing it. (Also avoid naming variables with special characters.)

Comment: mas esse é o código inteiro... tem algo que eu deveria colocar?
(but thats the entire code... is there anything that I should put in?)